# How to display custom field value on page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, customization

I have added custom fields by clicking on screen option and mark custom field ,how  to display custom field value on page?

Comment: See [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: If your issue is solved, please mark the answer that helped you :). If not, specify what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

See [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Getting_Custom_Fields)

Example:

```
 get_post_meta($post->ID, 'EXAMPLEFIELD', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using get_post_meta() fetch the custom field data

```
$key_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key', true );
// check if the custom field has a value
if( ! empty( $key_value ) ) {
  echo $key_value;
}
```

also see for more detail [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)